# Vroom error in reading multiple csv files in a folder

Tags: r, vroom

I have a vroom error when reading multiple csv files, the strange thing is that the code was made 9 months ago without any issues, so I am guessing something happened after package updates or Rstudio updates? How should I fix it? I am currently using Rstudio 4.3.1 (64-bit)
Not able to provide an example because these are privacy protected large registry datasets.

```
library(vroom)
library(fs)

lmdb_files<-dir_ls(glob="*.csv")

lmdb_files
lmdb2005.csv lmdb1995.csv lmdb1997.csv lmdb1998.csv lmdb1999.csv lmdb2000.csv lmdb2001.csv lmdb2002.csv lmdb2003.csv 
lmdb2004.csv lmdb2006.csv lmdb2007.csv lmdb2008.csv lmdb2009.csv lmdb2010.csv lmdb2011.csv lmdb2012.csv lmdb2013.csv 
lmdb2014.csv lmdb2015.csv lmdb2016.csv lmdb2017.csv lmdb2018.csv lmdb2019.csv lmdb2020.csv 

lmdb<-vroom(lmdb_files)

Fail in gsub("\"[^\"]*\"", "", lines) : input string 15 is invalid                                                                                           
In addition: Warning
In gsub("\"[^\"]*\"", "", lines) :
' to a wide stringate '"000001111111","EI",3/5/1997,1,,"00","Visk<f8>se ""DAK""","0,5%","S01",1,"PK","pakninger","BO",0.5,"PC",5
```

Comment: Further information: the dataset contains some special characters, such as æ ø å ... again, no issues previously. Also, I don't have any error messages reading single csv files in this folder using vroom, only when I batch-read multiple files.

Comment: Hard to guess, try to find the one CSV that fails, see what makes it fail.

Comment: If you use forloops, and loop over CSVs one by one, does it read without issues?

Comment: I have used a lapply function with vroom and it also fails.  Actually yes I can find single CSV files that also fails vroom, will try to see what is making it fail. What exactly does gsub input string mean? by input string 15, it's the 15th column that it's talking about?

Comment: Do you know what encoding was used for the character values in the file? When you have non-ascii characters, you want to make sure to specify the encoding so the import can properly decode the strings. This error is most likely from using the wrong encoding. What OS are you using? What OS were the files likely generated on?

Comment: Thanks@MrFlick, I believe it is caused by the wrong encoding for special characters too. Trouble is that I'm using a remote server to access these registry datasets, I can't even know what OS it is except that it is a Windows Server, and the datasets would have been generated on a Windows Server as well, but probably the server has gone through an update between the 9 months where the dataset is generated and now.

Comment: Is there a way to find out what encoding is on the csv file, or is there a way to tell vroom to try different types of encoding?